# how to change the tab widget size in TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

In my application i use the tabhost in linear layout, tabhost contains 4 tabs. The size of the tabwidget is very very high and it shows title very small. Can any one help me how to reduce the size of tabwidget.

Answer (score 4):

I would insist to create `custom Tabs` using [**setIndicator(View)**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator%28android.view.View%29). So, create a TextView of your desired size and set it to the TabWidget. [`Here`](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136) is an Tutorial for the same with Example.

You can just inflate a `TextView` and set it to the TabWidget using

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_custom_tab-layout,
                                                                           null);
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tv).
                                                              setContent(intent);
mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
```

Comment: Question: Is it possible to change the LayoutInflater dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on exactly what you're looking to do here, but I'll make a guess at it.

If you don't want space to be taken up by graphics (in other words, have text only) you can set the height and graviy of the widget to effectively remove the space that is used by the graphic, making for a much more compact tab label (vertically).

```
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="bottom" />
```

Comment: when i reduce the tabwidget height, the tabwidget titles are disappeared but the free space on tabwidget remains same.